# How can I remove a comma using jquery or javascript which is between html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've html code with a comma between it. I need to remove this comma. I tried different ways but could not do it.

can anyone please help me to remove this comma.

below is the code:

```
    <div class="crm-content">
      <div class="location vcard"><span class="adr">
        <span class="street-address">45 ABC Road</span><br>
        <span class="extended-address">test1</span><br>
        test2<br>
        <span class="locality">xyz<br></span>
        , 
        <span class="region">Berkshire<br></span>
        <span class="postal-code">AB4 3DK</span><br>
        <span class="country-name">United Kingdom</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

comma is after `<span class="locality">`

edit:

code I've tried using replace all. which is not working

```
console.log( document.querySelector('div.crm-content'));
result = document.querySelector('div.crm-content');

content = result.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried that didn't work please, otherwise it seems like you're just asking the community to do your work for you.

Comment: read about `childNodes` and `nextSibling`

Comment: i've tried with replace all. adding my code to the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the other question. that removes all the text between elements. in this scenario I only want to remove this comma, elements vary for different users(all spans will not be available all the time). anyhow thanks for help. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the comma with zero font size on the parent div element, then reset the preferred font size on the child span elements:

```
div.location {
  font-size: 0;
}
div.location span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the comma is always in the same spot, you can do:

```js
$('span.locality').get(0).nextSibling.remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crm-content">
  <div class="location vcard"><span class="adr">
        <span class="street-address">45 ABC Road</span><br>
    <span class="extended-address">test1</span><br> test2
    <br>
    <span class="locality">xyz<br></span> ,
    <span class="region">Berkshire<br></span>
    <span class="postal-code">AB4 3DK</span><br>
    <span class="country-name">United Kingdom</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.get(0)` gets the DOM node which enables you to use `.nextSibling` to get the text node after it, which contains your comma, and then remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. but i'm using on click function to do this. on every click its removing next element. :(

Comment: So instead of `.click()` use `.one()` so that it only runs once. Or unbind the click after you do it the first time.

Comment: I'm implementing this for copy to clipboard functionality. on this page user will have multiple addresses for copying. user may try several times. tried using `.one` samething happeningin this scenario.